# How to convert string to unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

How could I convert the following string:

```
std::string str = "xasxdfxtg";
```

to this following unsigned char array/byte array

```
unsigned char char_arr[1024] = "\xas\xdf\xtg";
```

Comment: HINT: your string doesn't contain backslashes

Comment: I see let me make them double.

Comment: So you want the `unsigned char` array to actually contain backslashes? Then you would write that with double backslashes in real C code, too.

Comment: Yes only single backslashes stores in the unsigned char array (byte array).

Comment: That is what my answer provides. The doubles in your `std::string` simply mean 'do not treat this as an escape sequence, but rather a literal backslash'. So you end up with just one byte in memory containing `'\'` for each pair of backslashes within a double-quoted (non-raw) C string.

Comment: @Radslev, If this is some sort of assignment or quiz question, can you please post the full text of the question. Because I think we have a misunderstanding of what you want, and there's a confusion with bytes, backslashes and escaping characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper algorithm: `std::copy()`, not `strcpy()`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::string str = "\\xas\\xdf\\xtg";
    unsigned char char_arr[1024]{};

    std::copy(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), char_arr);
    std::cout << char_arr << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
>  \xas\xdf\xtg
> ```

Comment: It's stores the string as "\\xas\\xdf\\xtg" not "\xas\xdf\xtg"

Comment: Edit your post to clarify what you actually want. My code does the logical thing.

Comment: In neither case here is either string stored with double backslashes in it. That is the C/C++ syntax to indicate literal backslashes within a non-raw string. rather than escape sequences, which a single backslash introduces. You can simply test this using a debugger or even just by printing each byte as an integer.

Comment: I've modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
std::string s{"\\xas\\xdf\\xtg"};
unsigned char char_arr[1024] {0}; // initialize with zeros to make sure after copy it's null terminated

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
{
    char_arr[i] = s[i];
}

std::cout << char_arr; // outputs \xas\xdf\xtg
```

Comment: Is it storing it as bytes? Or as \\x00\\x00?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, could you clarify please?

Comment: If I declare unsigned char char_arr[1024] = "\x00\x00" it will store the value as bytes, I believe your method stores the value as "\\x00\\x00"

Comment: So, I declared it as `unsigned char char_arr[1024] {0};`. This effectively initializes all bytes in this array to 0 (not `'0'` character but actual 0); 
"\\x00\\x00..." is a string which effectively has characters `\ `, `x` , `0`, `\ `, `x` , `0`. which will be some non-zero numbers in memory (134, 170, 48...)

Comment: Also I would suggest some reading and research to understand how the computer stores data in memory, because I believe that you need it in order to fully understand the problem you have and the solutions provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "\\xas\\xdf\\xtg";

    unsigned char char_arr[1024] {0};

    std::strcpy((char*)char_arr, str.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: will this store it as bytes?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this strcpy.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
 string str ="\\xas\\xdf\\xtg" ;
 unsigned char m_Test[20];
 strcpy( (char*) m_Test, str.c_str() );
  return 0;
}
```